# If any of 'words' in list, print the index(s) of list with the word(s) (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
#input list
lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi','python', 'pool']


if any(word in lst for word in ('def', 'kok', 'python')):
   print(lst.index(word))
else:
   print("string is not present")
```

Since the word 'def' and 'python' is in list at list[1] and list[3]. the output should be:

1

3

But I get.. NameError: name 'word' is not define. How would I make it print the desired results?

Comment: `word`'s scope is limited to only `any(...)`.

Comment: The output is not blank, it gives a `NameError: name 'word' is not defined`. Please provide the *exact* output, including the complete error traceback, corresponding to the right version of your code.

Comment: This code raises an error message. If your output is blank, something else (not only the code itself) is also wrong.

Comment: `word` is defined inside the generator `any()` looks through, you're trying to access it outside that, which won't work. If you're seeing nothing, it's probably because you are running the script in a way that doesn't show you the error message that will show if you just run it directly using Python.

Answer (score 1):

The `any` statement returns a boolean value only, you can't use what was given to it anymore. Then you can understand that `lst.index(word)` would give one value, not : all the indexes of words that are present

Compute the list of indexes for word that are present, then print them if there is any, or print the `else` string

```
lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'python', 'pool']

indexes = [lst.index(word) for word in ('def', 'kok', 'python') if word in lst]

if indexes:  
    print(*indexes)
else:
    print("string is not present")
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I also got it to print out one at a time by doing
For x in indexes: 
print x

Comment: @JayVan try `print(*indexes, sep="\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a comprehension with a `for` loop:

```
lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi','python', 'pool']

out = []
for word in ('def', 'kok', 'python'):
  if word in lst:
    out.append(word)
    print(f"string {word} is present on index {lst.index(word)}")
  else:
    print(f"string {word} is not present")
```

**Output:**

```
string def is present on index 1
string kok is not present
string python is present on index 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, although the printout should be the Index # of where that word was found within the list.  but I was able to get it working from azro

Comment: @jay-van I added the `index()` function to print the specific index

Answer (score 0):

Try without using "any" function:

```
lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi','python', 'pool']

for word in ('def', 'kok', 'python'):
    if word in lst:
        print(lst.index(word))
    else:
        print("string is not present")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using a set intersection.

You want to find out if any of the strings in a list *ref* exist in a list *lst* so...

```
lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi','python', 'pool']
ref = ['def', 'kok', 'python']

if c := set(lst).intersection(set(ref)):
    print(*(lst.index(k) for k in c), sep='\n')
else:
    print('string not present')
```

If there are no strings common to the two lists the intersection will return an empty set. In this particular case the set will contain two values - i.e., {'def','python'}

**Output:**

```
1
3
```